# Turn off or disallow fatal errors during script run?

Tags: perl

We have a while(1) script that loops through its' various workings, then sleeps for 60 seconds and then goes through it all again. This script needs to run 24/7.

As we add new functionality within the while(1) loop, or just over the course of random issues, sometimes they fail and unfortunately crash the entire script. The solution has been wrapping any such functions in eval{}, but my question is...Is there anyway to globally set that all errors or fatals do NOT halt/kill the entire script so we don't have to wrap everything around the eval{} ?

Comment: So, something like "I know I may have errors in my program... Just ignore them and do what I mean..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do – ignore any errors, carry on at all costs – is a very questionable practice, may bring your program into undefined state, and makes actual bugs even harder to find.

You *could* in theory override the `CORE::GLOBAL::die` subroutine to catch exceptions from your Perl code, but a real `die` is still available as the `CORE::die` sub, and this doesn't trap errors from XS code or perl itself (unlike using `eval`). Note that some modules use `die` and `warn` for control flow. Consider the following code:

```
sub foo {
  my ($x, $y) = @_;
  croak "X must be smaller than Y" unless $x < $y;
  return $y - $x;
}
```

Now if `die` becomes a `warn`, then that function could start to output negative numbers, wreaking all kind of havoc (e.g. when used for array indices).

*Please*, stay with the `eval` solution, or even better: migrate to [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny). Fatal errors exist for a reason.

---

If high reliability is a must, you may want to adopt an Erlang-like model: A pool of worker processes. If an error turns up, that process is killed, and a replacement process started.

Comment: Overriding `die` won't stop exceptions from `perl` itself and XS modules.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks, clarified

Comment: Inside the while(1) loop is a foreach loop and for each of the instances in the loop, runs a set of commands. The hope was that even if one of those commands fatally dies, the worst it can do is die that foreach instance and go on to the next until the foreach is done. The "mission critical" component being that EVERY instance of the foreach MUST run. I think our best practice is indeed to wrap every command that can potentially wreak havoc into an eval{}.

Answer (score 3):

That makes no sense. How would the program know where to resume? You must tell it where, and you do that using `eval`.

You would surely be better writing a wrapper for the script that logs failures and restarts the script.

Comment: The while(1) has a foreach loop inside it, each of those instances runs a set of commands. If a fatal error occurs, instead of die'ing the entire script, it should just die that particular command/instance and go to the next foreach instance.

We actually already have a wrapper, but in the case of a die'ing command, the script just constantly restarts (via wrapper) and dies at the same spot, instead of continuing to the next command.

Comment: I don't know why you're telling me this as I've already coverered this: You want to resume somewhere specific. How do you expect `perl` to know where that is if you don't tell it? You have to tell it using `eval`. Replace `while (1) { ... }` with `while (1) { warn $@ if !eval { ... 1 }; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the other answers, the fact is that some errors may not be easily recoverable and just ignoring them and trudging along could easily cause unwanted behavior. Another option is to remove the `while` loop so that the script only executes once, and call it from `cron`, which allows you to run programs on a schedule. For example, you might open a shell and call `crontab -e` to edit the scheduler and add this line:

```
* * * * * perl /path/to/script.pl
```

which will run your script every minute and send you a mail with the output if there is any, including warnings and errors.